# Serialization Dilemma

Tags: c++, serialization, messaging

While writing code for my application, I have come across this problem quite frequently and I do not know correct way to handle it.

Suppose I need to write code to represent a PRE-DEFINED network messaging protocol.  Messages come in as an array of bytes (with a known length) that I need to transform into a class.

Here is an example of a message in the protocol:

```
+-----------+---....---+
| Operation |   Data   |
+-----------+---....---+
```

Where Operation is a single byte (the first byte in the serialized data) and Data is the remaining bytes.

I would normally think the represent the "class" as such:

```
struct MyMessage {
    enum Operation : uint8_t {
        A = 0x00,
        B = 0x01,
        C = 0x02
    }

    Operation operation;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
};
```

After doing a TON of research on the different serialization protocols available, I believe I understand that the process of serializing this structure comes down to writing some "serialize" function which breaks the struct into its primitive values and serializes them (which in turn might need to be broken down into more primitive values).

For example:

```
template <typename ARCHIVE>
bool serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, const MyMessage& v) {
    archive.visit(v.operation);
    archive.visit(v.data);
}
```

Here's the problem, normally, a variable-sized array of some data should always be serialized with the length included as additional data.  However, in the pre-defined messaging structure I need to follow, the length is NOT included and is merely assumed to be "the rest of the data in the bytes that were sent to you."  Thus, I do not see how it's possible to write a generic serialize function for this class that a) allows it to be serialized into the required format and b) also be serialized into a standard format to be stored in, for example, a file.

For example, in my serialize function above, the std::vector should include the "length" field when serialized to any other format than the message structure.

I read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3262713/13320909 that perhaps one of my problems is the separation of "serialization" from "messaging," but I'm not sure.

Any help understanding what to do about this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will it be possible to send data as multiple packets/messages with some extra data like packet number x of y and total valid bytes in that packet? So you can reconstruct the larger data structure at the other end.

Comment: What if you have a *streaming* protocol to transmit the data, like a TCP connection? How would the receiver know how much to actually receive? When the data actually ends? Even when using a file it would be impossible for the reader to know when one `MyMessage` data ends, and the operation of the next starts.

Comment: When you implement serialization, you adhere to a protocol - this may be an officially sanctioned one, like TCP, or JSON, or whatever, or it may one of your own making. As long as both sides agree on the protocol (sender/receiver, storer/loader), you should be fine.

Comment: @PepijnKramer  In the existing protocol, serialized "messages" are ALWAYS contained within packets which DO contain headers and length information.  So yes, it would be possible to put two messages end-to-end but ONLY when encapsulated inside the packets.

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever have one vector then you can calculate the size from the message size. But that's unlikely.

But nothing stops you from turning a vector into a blob of `std::byte` that consists of the length + all the elements serialized. Your message format only sees a blob of N bytes, what you make of that is your decision.

Similar if you have a union (std::variant, std::optional, std::any) you turn it into a blob that encodes the type followed by the serialization of the data.

What works for me is for all classes to inherit a Serializable base class and provide functions for `serialized_length`, `serialize` and `deserialize`. The first one is used to compute the size of the buffer to allocate when serializing a class. For anything without dynamic content it's a constexpr.

Comment: Note: `std::string` is best serialized into length + data too.

Comment: This is similar to what I had in my code at one point.  The only problem is, "serialized_length" could/should be different depending on the serializer itself.  For example, I should be able to write a "HumanFriendlySerializer" or "JSONSerializer" class without changing the implementation of the "serialize" function.  In these examples, the serialized length is obviously different/the class doesn't know.

Comment: @PatrickWright I would solve that with a dependency injection or pass a SerialiseHelper as extra argument. The helper would have functions to compute the length for fundamental types or containers, e.g. length of a vector is the sum of the elements + (n - 1) * ',' + enclosing '[]' for json. If you want human friendly you might have to use a more complex size type so you can adjust for indentation as you merge data into larger and larger objects.

Comment: @PatrickWright Different serialization formats are different. What if you wanted a format like this one, but where the data does have a length?